# Laravel 5.3 - Form model binding select boxes

Tags: laravel-5

I have 3 select boxes in a Form and I want to make model binding but it doesn't work. These are my select boxes in form

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('worktype_list1', 'Servicekräfte: ', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-2">
    {!! Form::select('worktype_list[]', $worktypes, null, ['id' => 'worktype_list1', 'class' => 'col-md-2 form-control', 'required']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('worktype_list2', 'Servicekräfte: ', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-2">
    {!! Form::select('worktype_list[]', $worktypes, null, ['id' => 'worktype_list2', 'class' => 'col-md-2 form-control', 'required']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('worktype_list3', 'Servicekräfte: ', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-2">
    {!! Form::select('worktype_list[]', $worktypes, null, ['id' => 'worktype_list3', 'class' => 'col-md-2 form-control', 'required']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the store method:

```
public function store(UrequestsForm $request)
{

    //dd($request->all());
    $urequest = Auth::user()->requests()->create($request->all());

    $urequest->worktypes()->attach($request->input('worktype_list'));

    return redirect('urequests')->with('success', 'Anfrage erfolgreich gemacht!');
}
```

The validation is working fine and saving, but when I go to edit view
in every select box is the same and has the same options selected. I have followed the tutorial on Laracasts, and this works for multiple select box but not for single item select.

Comment: Why have you got 3 arrays for `worktype_list`?

Comment: It is wrong....i have followed the tutorial but in tutorial there is a multiple select box....and my select box is single select. I would appreciate if you could help me

Comment: How to save each checkbox as it's own value

Comment: Do you not want to use a multiple select?

Comment: No...just one selected option....so i need to adjust my store method... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert an array with the selected IDs in the third parameter.

```
{!! Form::select('worktype_list[]', $worktypes, ARRAY_WITH_SELECTED_IDS, ['id' => 'worktype_list1', 'class' => 'col-md-2 form-control', 'required']) !!}
```

Comment: Hmm but i'm using the same form for both create and edit views...wouldn't that make an error at create form...

Comment: You can use something like `isset($variable) ? $variable : null`

Comment: So in order for this to work i actually can't have the same form for create and update....i needed to make an \@if() \@else \@endif statement to separate them on the same page